# How do I open a JFrame from a button click

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I making a game but I have a main meny and too outer menys and I want to open one of the menys by clicking on the respective button in the JFrame.

code of main.java

```java
package main;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import game.client.mainClient;
import game.server.mainServer;

public class main extends JPanel {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6590770928148744094L;

    private JLabel jcomp1;
    private JButton jcomp5;
    private JButton jcomp6;
    private JLabel jcomp8;
    private JLabel jcomp9;
    private JLabel jcomp10;



    public main() {
        //construct components
        jcomp1 = new JLabel ("test game");
        jcomp5 = new JButton ("singel player");
        jcomp6 = new JButton ("multiplayer");
        jcomp8 = new JLabel ("this game is made by kebe_");
        jcomp9 = new JLabel ("gui is made in guigenie");
        jcomp10 = new JLabel ("game verision dev 1.0");

        //adjust size and set layout
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension (681, 466));
        setLayout (null);

        //add components
        add (jcomp1);
        add (jcomp5);
        add (jcomp6);
        add (jcomp8);
        add (jcomp9);
        add (jcomp10);

        //set component bounds (only needed by Absolute Positioning)
        jcomp1.setBounds (295, 5, 70, 25);
        jcomp5.setBounds (265, 30, 115, 30);
        jcomp6.setBounds (265, 65, 115, 30);
        jcomp8.setBounds (0, 430, 180, 25);
        jcomp9.setBounds (0, 415, 155, 20);
        jcomp10.setBounds (0, 445, 140, 25);

        // close and open
        // singleplayer
        jcomp5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
                mainClient mc = new mainClient();
                mc.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        // multiplayer
        jcomp6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
                mainServer ms = new mainServer();
                ms.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Test game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add (new main());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }
}
```

code of mainClient.java

```java
package game.client;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class mainClient extends JPanel
{
    /**
     * 
    */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1271816540338950462L;

    private JLabel jcomp1;
    private JComboBox jcomp2;
    private JButton jcomp3;

    public mainClient() {
        //construct preComponents
        String[] jcomp2Items = {"save 1", "save 2", "save 3", "save 4", "save 5"};

        //construct components
        jcomp1 = new JLabel ("singel player");
        jcomp2 = new JComboBox (jcomp2Items);
        jcomp3 = new JButton ("play selected save");

        //adjust size and set layout
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension (681, 466));
        setLayout (null);

        //add components
        add (jcomp1);
        add (jcomp2);
        add (jcomp3);

        //set component bounds (only needed by Absolute Positioning)
        jcomp1.setBounds (290, 5, 85, 25);
        jcomp2.setBounds (280, 30, 100, 25);
        jcomp3.setBounds (255, 70, 150, 25);

        jcomp3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }


    public static void main (String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Singel player");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add (new mainClient());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }
}
```

code of mainServer

```java
package game.server;


import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class mainServer extends JPanel
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2726545572728204122L;

    private JLabel jcomp1;
    private JButton jcomp2;
    private JButton jcomp3;

    public mainServer() {
        //construct components
        jcomp1 = new JLabel ("multiplayer");
        jcomp2 = new JButton ("host game");
        jcomp3 = new JButton ("join game");

        //adjust size and set layout
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension (681, 466));
        setLayout (null);

        //add components
        add (jcomp1);
        add (jcomp2);
        add (jcomp3);

        //set component bounds (only needed by Absolute Positioning)
        jcomp1.setBounds (300, 0, 75, 25);
        jcomp2.setBounds (285, 25, 100, 25);
        jcomp3.setBounds (285, 50, 100, 25);
    }


    public static void main (String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Multiplayer");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add (new mainServer());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }
}
```

how can I open the JFrame in mainClient.java when I click on the singleplayer button, and the JFrame in mainServer.java when I click on the multiplayer button?

Comment: What is "meny"?

Comment: Matrix4290 the meny is the main frame in the main.java

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: .. 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create ActionListeners for your buttons. Define your frames, and you can access them with your class name. For example;

```
class mainClient extends JPanel {
    JFrame mainClientFrame = new JFrame();
}
```

and then;

```
mainClient mc = new mainClient();
mc.mainClientFrame.setVisible(true);
```

if you want to use this frames in your main void, define them static.

```
class mainClient extends JPanel {
    static JFrame mainClientFrame = new JFrame();
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the help but i dosen't open the "real" frame in mainClient i just open the window whit nothing in it

Comment: You should write your frame properties in mainClient's constructor.